# ETL process using Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, spyder

1. Load the CSV file (using Python).
2. Output the total number of rows and columns.
3. Output the number of non-null rows (by column).
4. Output the number of null values (by column).
5. Output the number of null values for all columns.
6. Output the number of duplicate rows

```
    import pandas as pd

    def main():
        df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\aliceoc\.spyder-py3\ProgrammingforBigDataCA\fireAndAmbulance (3).csv")
        print(df)
    main()


    def analysingData(df):
        print("Total number of rows: ",df.shape[0])
        print("Total number of columns",df.shape[1])
        print("Rows with empty columns:")
        for i in range(len(df.index)):
            print("empty column in row", i, df.iloc[i].isnull().sum())
        duplicate = df.duplicated(subset=None).sum()
        print(duplicate)
        print(df.count(axis=0))
        print()
    analysingData(r"C:\Users\aliceoc\.spyder-py3\ProgrammingforBigDataCA\fireAndAmbulance (3).csv")
```

I would like to see the number of rows, columns, rows with empty columns and duplicates. Some of it seems to work but other parts don't. I am not sure why.

Comment: Which parts work and which parts don't?

Comment: I'm actually not 100% to be honest. I'm finding it hard in the python console to figure out where I am wrong and where I am right.

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing a dataframe to analysingData.. you're passing the path+filename.